# PHP & Arrays: check if long array1 with 1s and 0s contains short array2 with just 1s, get keys and match keys against array3

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of 1s and 0s.

Example:

```
array1(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

I need to check if this array contains another array:

```
array2(1,1)
```

And I need to get the keys for all instances where it occurs and then match the key against another array of dates.

Example:

```
array3(20140425,20140426,20140427,20140428,20140429,20140430,20140501,20140502,20140503,20140504,20140505,20140506,20140507,20140508,20140509,20140510,20140511,20140512,20140513,20140514,20140515,20140516,20140517,20140518,20140519)
```

The arrays cannot be reordered.

In the example above the result of checking if array1 contains array2 might be:

```
9,16,17,18,19… etc…
```

Then the corresponding check against array3 would yield:

```
20140504,20140511,20140512,20140513,20140514 etc.
```

I believe `array_search` and `array_keys` might hold the answers but cannot get my head around it right now after two weeks solid hacking at data.

Comment: your question and/or requirements are ambiguous. Why you've 16 AND 17 in first match result?

Comment: One possible solution would be to implode the arrays into strings, and then do a preg_match returning the index of every match.

Comment: Thanks @Ejay. It is possible that in the example the resultant keys would be 9,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23. These are where pairs of 1,1 exist. It is just for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with built in functions. I would do it "by foot":

```
// Define data
$source=array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
$search=array(1, 1);
$dates=array(20140425, 20140426, 20140427, 20140428, 20140429, 20140430, 20140501, 20140502, 20140503, 20140504, 20140505, 20140506, 20140507, 20140508, 20140509, 20140510, 20140511, 20140512, 20140513, 20140514, 20140515, 20140516, 20140517, 20140518, 20140519);

// Search second array in first
$hits=array();
for ($a=0; $a<count($source); $a++)
{
    $found=true;
    for ($b=0; $b<count($search); $b++)
        if ($source[$a+$b]!=$search[$b])
        {
            $found=false;
            break;
        }
    if ($found) $hits[]=$a;
}

// Create a list of matching dates
$result=array();
foreach ($hits as $hit) $result[]=$dates[$hit];
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Hey @Wolfgang I'm getting an undefined offset error with this line: if ($source[$a+$b]!=$search[$b])

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to get your request :) The following code should work:

```
$r = array(); // result
for($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
  $test = true;
  for($k = 0; $k < count($array2); $k++)
  {
    if(!isset( $array1[$i+$k]) ||  $array1[$i+$k] != $array2[$k]) {
      $test = false;
    }
  }
  if($test)
  {
    $r[] = $array3[$i];
  }
}
```

Lg

Comment: Hey @Sebb I'm getting an undefined offset error with this line: if($array1[$i+$k] != $array2[$k]). Thinking it might be $k.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a quicker way but this works:

```
$haystack = implode($array1);
$needle   = implode($array2);
$key = -1;

while(($key = strpos($haystack, $needle, $key+1)) !== false) {
    if(isset($array3[$key])) {
        $result[$key] = $array3[$key];
    }
}
```

You could just use `$result[] = $array3[$key];` but I added `$result[$key]` so you have a record of where it was found.

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3710fab346b8d1451e8a719f4423552b2020c49d)